# How to cancel the last method called?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Minobot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x,self.y = 0, 0
        self.angle = 90

    def forward(self, d):
        angle = radians(90-self.angle)
        nx, ny = self.x + d * cos(angle), self.y + d * sin(angle)
        self.x, self.y = nx, ny

    def right(self):
        self.angle += 90

    def left(self):
        self.angle -= 90

    def coordinates(self):
        return round(self.x, 1), round(self.y, 1)

    def manhattan_distance(self):
        return int(abs(round(self.x, 1))+abs(round(self.y, 1)))

    def cancel(self):
        ????
```

Now I need to add another method to this class that cancels the last method called.
For example: a.forward(2) => a.right() => a.cancel() This would set the Minobot before the a.right() is used.

Comment: You'd have to keep a list of the steps that the Minobot has followed so that you can arrange to undo whatever changes/steps need to be cancelled.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot cancel the last action unless you store it.

If you store the last action, you can invert it. Since you know the reverse action once you take an action, you can just store the reverse action directly.

Let your `Minibot` instance have a `.reverse_action` attribute which is a tuple of the method to call and arguments to pass.

So

```
def left(self):
   # Note how methods can just be stored in variables.
   self.reverse_action = (self.right, ())
   ...

def forward(self, distance):
   # Forward is its own reverse with a negative distance.
   self.reverse_action = (self.forward, (-distance,))

def revert_last(self):
   if self.reverse_action:
      (method, args) = self.reverse_action
      method(*args)  # Call the stored method, passing stored args.
      self.reverse_action = None  # Used it up.
```

This has an obvious downside of being able to only revert one last action. If you store a *list* of reverse actions for each action you take, you can `.pop()` from it and revert actions as long as there are any stored reverse actions in the list.

You can store only last several actions if you're taking great many actions and are memory-constrained. (Terms to google up: "Undo buffer", "Circular buffer", "Event sourcing".)

Another approach would be storing the previous *state*, that is, coordinates, heading, etc. Undoing the last action would be then just switching to the previous state:

```
def save_state(self):
  self.previous_state = (self.x, self.y, self.angle)
  # Or: self.previous_states_list.append(...)

def restore_previous_state(self):
  (self.x, self.y, self.angle) = self.previous_state
  # Or: ... = self.previous_states_list.pop()

def left(self): 
  self.save_state()
  ...
```

This approach is free from rounding errors, etc. It takes more memory, though, especially as your state grows large, and when you want to save an entire history of previous states.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than saving the reversing action as other answers have suggested, you can save all the properties, and `cancel` can restore them.

```
class Minobot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x,self.y, self.oldx, self.oldy = 0, 0
        self.angle, self.oldangle = 90

    def forward(self, d):
        self.oldx, self.oldy = self.x, self.y
        angle = radians(90-self.angle)
        nx, ny = self.x + d * cos(angle), self.y + d * sin(angle)
        self.x, self.y = nx, ny

    def right(self):
        self.oldangle = self.angle
        self.angle += 90

    def left(self):
        self.oldangle = self.angle
        self.angle -= 90

    def coordinates(self):
        return round(self.x, 1), round(self.y, 1)

    def manhattan_distance(self):
        return int(abs(round(self.x, 1))+abs(round(self.y, 1)))

    def cancel(self):
        self.angle, self.x, self.y = self.oldangle, self.oldx, self.oldy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the last action and run it in reverse:
(thank you to the guy that made me update with lambdas)

```
class Minobot:
def __init__(self):
    self.x,self.y = 0, 0
    self.angle = 90
def forward(self, d):
    angle = radians(90-self.angle)
    nx, ny = self.x + d * cos(angle), self.y + d * sin(angle)
    self.x, self.y = nx, ny
    self.undo = lambda:self.forward(-d)

def right(self):
    self.angle += 90
    self.undo = lambda:self.left()

def left(self):
    self.angle -= 90
    self.undo = lambda:self.right()

def coordinates(self):
    return round(self.x, 1), round(self.y, 1)

def manhattan_distance(self):
    return int(abs(round(self.x, 1))+abs(round(self.y, 1)))

def cancel(self):
    self.undo()
```

Note: will cause a problem if you run cancel without something to cancel

Comment: Wouldn't a lambda be better than parsing a string?

Comment: Thanks good point I'll updage hopefully without making you angry again :P

Answer (score 1):

You could try keeping a records of all previous states, but memory usage could grow to be larger than you want. In the solution shown below, the pickle protocol is used to get and set the state of the object as needed. Please note that if you pickle instances of the following class, the instance will not keep its history. The code will probably need to be adapted to your particular requirements.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import math


class MinnowBot:
    __slots__ = '__x', '__y', '__angle', '__history'

    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 0
        self.__y = 0
        self.__angle = 90

    def forward(self, distance):
        self.history.append(self.__getstate__())
        angle = math.radians(90 - self.__angle)
        self.__x += distance * math.cos(angle)
        self.__y += distance * math.sin(angle)

    def right(self):
        self.history.append(self.__getstate__())
        self.__angle += 90

    def left(self):
        self.history.append(self.__getstate__())
        self.__angle -= 90

    @property
    def coordinates(self):
        return round(self.__x, 1), round(self.__y, 1)

    @property
    def manhattan_distance(self):
        return round(abs(self.__x) + abs(self.__y))

    def cancel(self):
        self.__setstate__(self.history.pop())

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.__x, self.__y, self.__angle

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__x, self.__y, self.__angle = state

    @property
    def history(self):
        try:
            history = self.__history
        except AttributeError:
            # noinspection PyAttributeOutsideInit
            history = self.__history = []
        return history
```

Answer (score 0):

With you short explain maybe you can add state attribute and:

```
class Minobot:
  def __init__(self):
      self.x,self.y = 0, 0
      self.angle = 90
      self.state = self.__init__
      self.d = 0

  def forward(self, d=None):
      if d is None:
          d = self.d
      angle = radians(90-self.angle)
      nx, ny = self.x + d * cos(angle), self.y + d * sin(angle)
      self.x, self.y = nx, ny
      self.d = d
      self.state = self.forward

  def right(self):
      self.angle += 90
      self.state = self.left

  def left(self):
      self.angle -= 90
      self.state = self.right

  def coordinates(self):
      return round(self.x, 1), round(self.y, 1)

  def manhattan_distance(self):
      return int(abs(round(self.x, 1))+abs(round(self.y, 1)))

  def cancel(self):
      if self.state is None:
          pass
      else:
          state = self.state
          self.state = None
          return state()
```

Comment: How does setting `self.state` to the same method that was called make it undo the action?

Comment: I still don't see how `self.state = self.forward` works. Don't you need to go backward, and remember the distance?

Answer (score 0):

If memory is not a concern, you can store/restore state by saving/restoring the whole object.

I am also considering that control of the target object outside its class is not a problem. I assume the object is not cancelling the last action itself, but some other code controls that. Otherwise you'll have to manage your class relation with the Stack class.

In the below example I use `deepcopy`, but `pickle.dumps` can also be used.
I choose to use a stack like structure, which allows the saving of whatever number of objects/states you want. But replacing with a rotating buffer would allow the storage of only the last n objects/states.

The advantage I see over some of the other answers is not worrying about what methods were called or attributes had changed. It's also simple. Preserving states and frames/environments always remembers me of dicts and stacks:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class ObjectStack():

    def __init__(self):
        self.objects = []

    def push(self, obj):
        self.objects.append(deepcopy(obj))

    def pop(self):
        return self.objects.pop() if self.objects else None

#just an example class, not OP's original class
class char():
    def __init__(self, char):
        self.char = char

stack = ObjectStack()

c = char('C')
stack.push(c) # save object

c = char('D') # somehow object changes
print(c.char)

last = stack.pop() # restore last object/state
if last is not None:
    c = last
    print(c.char)

last = stack.pop()
if last is None:
    print('No more objects/states saved')
```